# How to recursively go through folders and count total file size

Tags: c, file, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to recursively go through my directories and print file size, then at the end print the total of all file size's. I cannot figure out what to pass my function recursively, and my variable total does not end up being correct,any help is greatly appreciated, thanks so much in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void do_ls(char[]);
int total = 0;

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if (ac == 1)
        do_ls(".");
    else
    {
        while (--ac) {
            printf("%s:\n", *++av);
            do_ls(*av);
        }
    }
}

void do_ls(char dirname[])
{
    DIR *dir_ptr;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    struct stat info;

    if ((dir_ptr = opendir(dirname)) == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "ls01: cannot opern %s\n", dirname);
    else
    {
        while((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL) {
            stat(direntp->d_name, &info);
            if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
                printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name);
                //I believe recursion goes here, I tried the following 
                //do_ls(direntp->d_name);
            else
                printf("%d %s\n", (int)info.st_size, direntp->d_name);
                total += (int)info.st_size;
        }
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
    printf("Your total is: %d \n", total);
}
```

Comment: Instead of declaring `do_ls` as void, let it return the number you are looking for!

Comment: Not everything is clear for me, but for recursion you didn't change the directory. You may change it to dirname if it isn't a dot, but if it's a single dot - seems you need to change it to what you found and then recursively `do_ls(".")`... Or better way: `do_ls(dirname + '/' + direntp->d_name);` if you don't want to change it.

Comment: @kay27 note this is C

Comment: I am a little confused, I am not familiar with this stuff very much at all. I tried putting do_ls(".") where i put my comment but it seems to just keep going forever. I also tried putting do_ls(dirname + '/' + direntp->d_name); however that was giving me some errors. Any more help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in general, you want the code to be checking for directory names of `.` or `..` and not processing those names,  In general, you will find those directory names in every directory the code encounters

Comment: In addition to what @user3629249 said: single dot means current working directory (CWD); double dot means parent directory. So you maybe gotta handle it at your first step, but you need to skip them further to prevent infinite loop like ./././././././. ...

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
while((direntp - readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL)
```

you should be setting direntp, not subtracting (I assume).