# How do I recursively go through folders and count total file size?

Tags: c, file, recursion, directory

I am trying to make this work recursively so when it finds a folder it goes into the folder and finds the file size, then at the end print the total of all file sizes. However I cannot figure out how to get this to work recursively, I have tried many things. Also my count for total does not end up correctly even when I am not doing recursion. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void do_ls(char[]);
int total = 0;

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if (ac == 1)
        do_ls(".");
    else
    {
        while (--ac) {
            printf("%s:\n", *++av);
            do_ls(*av);
        }
    }
}

void do_ls(char dirname[])
{
    DIR *dir_ptr;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    struct stat info;

    if ((dir_ptr = opendir(dirname)) == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "ls01: cannot opern %s\n", dirname);
    else
    {
        while((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL) {
            stat(direntp->d_name, &info);
            if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
                printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name);
                //I believe recursion goes here, I tried the following 
                //do_ls(direntp->d_name);
                //do_ls(".");
                //do_ls(dirname + '/' + direntp->d_name);
                //none of these seemed to work.
            else
                printf("%d %s\n", (int)info.st_size, direntp->d_name);
                total += (int)info.st_size;
        }
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
    printf("Your total is: %d \n", total);
}
```

Comment: Note: It's more conventional to pass `char*` than `char[]`.

Comment: First step: Extract a [mcve]. In particular leaving us to guess what to pass to the program is inacceptable. Hard-code the values that don't work. Also, what exactly is the problem? Is it determining the file sizes or is it navigating through the directory tree? Eliminate either one from your MCVE.

Comment: Can you just use `du`?

Comment: @user3121023 how would I pass it the full path?

Comment: @ColbyBarton you have create a new string that concatenates dirname, a path separator (like `/`) and `direntp->d_name` to form the full path to pass into the recursive call to `do_ls`.

Comment: Note: a similar question was [asked by OP recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091932/how-to-recursively-go-through-folders-and-count-total-file-size).

Comment: I prepared an answer for yesterday's similar question, which constructed a pathname for the recursion: from the pathname passed as an argument, and the directory name found by `readdir` etc. But as a Windows man, was unsure whether that is reentrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a directory entry to recurse into, you must construct the path by concatenating the directory and the entry name with a `/` separator and call `do_ls` recursively.

In order to compute file sizes, you can use the `stat` system call, but you will need the pathname too, so construct is before testing for the entry type (use `malloc` to allocate space for the concatenated string) and do not forget to free it after use.

Also ignore the `.` and `..` entries and move the `closedir()` out of the `while` loop.

Here is an improved version that does not use a global variable for the 
`total` size, but instead returns the cumulative size to the caller:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

long long do_ls(const char *name) {
    DIR *dir_ptr;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    struct stat info;
    long long total = 0;
    int output = 1;

    if (stat(name, &info)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ls01: cannot stat %s\n", name);
        return 0;
    }
    if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) {
        if ((dir_ptr = opendir(name)) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ls01: cannot open directory %s\n", name);
        } else {
            while ((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL) {
                char *pathname;

                /* ignore current and parent directories */
                if (!strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".."))
                    continue;

                pathname = malloc(strlen(name) + 1 + strlen(direntp->d_name) + 1);
                if (pathname == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ls01: cannot allocated memory\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                sprintf(pathname, "%s/%s", name, direntp->d_name);
                total += do_ls(pathname);
                free(pathname);
            }
            closedir(dir_ptr);
        }
    } else {
        total = info.st_size;
    }
    printf("%10lld  %s\n", total, name);
    return total;
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    int i = 1;

    if (i >= ac) {
        do_ls(".");
    } else {
        long long total = 0;
        while (i < ac) {
            total += do_ls(av[i++]);
        }
        printf("total is: %lld\n", total);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that [per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html), "[t]he `readdir()` function need not be thread-safe."  It is [thread-safe on current versions of glibc/Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), however:  "However, in modern implementations
       (including the glibc implementation), concurrent calls to `readdir()`
       that specify different directory streams are thread-safe."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: granted `readdir` may not always be thread-safe, the OP did not give any indication he was going to use this function in a threaded environment. Re-entrancy is not an issue here either, multiple `dirent` streams can be opened and enumerated independently, nested or not.

Comment: Thank you @chqrlie so much for the feedback, it was greatly appreciated and helped fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

When you have the filename building working as already advised, the global

```
int total = 0;
```

is inadequate for summing the size of files with

```
total += (int)info.st_size;
```

so I suggest

```
uint64_t total;
```

and then

```
total += info.st_size;
```

Besides that a global is poor practice, which can be improved by returning a value from the recursive function, when you have it working. The total then can be summed within the recursive function.

```
uint64_t do_ls(char[]);
```